# DOMAttrModified event listener is not firing in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have worked on injecting scripts into a third party mobile website. I am using User Agent Switcher plugin for Firefox to inspect elements of mobile website in desktop environment.

In firefox I have tested DOMAttrModified event using break on attribute change for a particular DOM element, but in Android WebView the event is not fired.

```
element.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function (ev) {
  // ...
}, false);
```

I don't know why it is not working in Android WebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isDOMAttrModifiedSupported() {
var p, flag;

flag = false;
p = document.createElement('p');
if (p.addEventListener) {
    p.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', callback, false);
}
else if (p.attachEvent) {
    p.attachEvent('onDOMAttrModified', callback);
}
else {
    // Assume not
    return false;
}
p.setAttribute('id', 'target');
return flag;

function callback() {
    flag = true;
}
```

}

check this code.